# What is the exact solution to $x^{x^{-1/x}} = 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is the exact solution of this equation?
>   $$x^{x^{-1/x}} = 2$$

I for the life of me have not been able to figure it out nor have I been able to find anything online that would be able to even get me started.

Answer (score 2):

Do not expect an explicit solution for the equation
$$x^{x^{-1/x}}=2$$ which can only be solved using numerical methods.

If you plot the lhs, you will notice that the solution is close to $x=3$ and that, around this value, the lhs is almost linear (this is good news). So, let us use Newton method with $x_0=3$ and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 3.0000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 2.7231817852467105312 \\
 2 & 2.7220005777936185465 \\
 3 & 2.7220005621935536562 \\
 4 & 2.7220005621935536535
\end{array}
\right)$$
This number is not identified by inverse symbolic calculators.

*Just for the fun of it*, this number can be *approximated* by
$$x=\frac{746 e^2+367 e-77}{379 e^2+171 e-902}=2.7220005621935536538$$
Injecting this value, the lhs is $2.0000000000000000002$.

**Edit**

Taking logarithms, you could consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x \log (\log (x))-kx -\log (x)\qquad \text{with} \qquad k=\log (\log (2))$$ Expanding as a Taylor series around $x=e$ would give
$$f(x)=-(e k+1)+\left(-k-\frac{1}{e}+1\right) (x-e)+O\left((x-e)^2\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms the gives
$$x \sim e-\frac{e (e k+1)}{e (k-1)+1}\approx 2.722001500$$ which is not bad as an approximation.

In fact, expanding to first order corresponds to the first iterate of Newton method.

Let us do it with Halley method and get for the first iterate
$$x\sim e-\frac{2 e (e (k-1)+1) (e k+1)}{e \left(2 e (k-1)^2+5 k-4\right)+3}\approx 2.722000562$$

For the fun, let us continue with Householder method and get for the first iterate
$$x\sim e-\frac{3 e (e k+1) \left(e \left(2 e (k-1)^2+5 k-4\right)+3\right)}{e \left(34   k+2 e (k-1) (13 k-9)+e^2 (k (k (6 k-19)+18)-6)-25\right)+14}$$ which is
$2.72200056219156$

You almost have an analytical solution.

Now, using one iteration of high order [iterative methods](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/newton.html)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_{(n)} & \text{method}\\
 1 & 2.7220014995535917953 & \text{Newton} \\
 2 & 2.7220005620261286697 & \text{Halley} \\
 3 & 2.7220005621915662442 & \text{Householder} \\
 4 & 2.7220005621935614452 & \text{no name} \\
 5 & 2.7220005621935536322 & \text{no name} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
\infty & 2.7220005621935536535
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the equation $x^{x^{-1/x}} = 2$ can be re-expressed as

$$x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln(\ln x) - \ln(\ln 2)}$$

Also note that the actual value of $x$ is very close to $e$. Thus, a good analytic approximation can be obtained by replacing $x= e$ on the RHS, i.e.

$$x = -\frac1{\ln(\ln 2)} = 2.7284 $$